# How could I reformat a question with answers already provided?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it OK (and right) to change the question to a more general one (which makes it more useful, but also makes some of the already given answers incorrect)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31708/is-it-ok-and-right-to-change-the-question-to-a-more-general-one-which-makes-i)

I posted this question about half an hour ago: [What's the difference between using Url.Content and not doing so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178826/whats-the-difference-between-using-url-content-and-not-doing-so)

After the first answer, I quickly realized my ignorance (and that my question was poorly constructed). Now I feel like editing the question heavily to be more specific about what I wanted an answer for, also to make it relevant to others in the future.

*But...*

There's already an answer there that tells me I'm wrong, trying to explain the "~"-symbol which I didn't actually ask about (since I know it).

If I edited it, it could mean that the answer provided becomes odd/irrelevant. On the other hand, I might get some more precise answers.

Any advice?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31708/

Comment: What exactly is it that you wanted to ask? If you provide us some more information here, we could try to give you some guidance as to how a new questions could be written more concisely.

Comment: @Jim I wanted to know what you gain from using Url.Content. In my haste I hadn't checked that, without it, you couldn't use relative paths (obviously because I don't know exactly what's happening behind the code). Now, I think the introduction part is a bit irrelevant, but coming to think of it, I can't really ask about Url.Content in a way that isn't changing the question.

Comment: It looks like you've got an answer, then. I'm not sure what else it is you want to ask....

Answer (score 4):

If you already have answers that **answer** your original question, **Accept them** and move on.

Ask a new question, there is **nothing** wrong with that!

**DO NOT** just change your Original Post to a completely different question.

Comment: Even if it's almost the same question?

Comment: @AskeB. _almost_ the same is **not** the same as _same_. Notice the **almost**?

Comment: It is like saying chicken is _almost the same_ as beef.

Comment: Secondly. I asked a stupid question and got an answer I'm not really satisfied with. I don't see a reason to accept an answer that didn't answer my question. Because then how would it be relevant to others?

Comment: @AskeB. so don't accept the answer if ti did not help you, but **never** change the question.

Answer (score 1):

You say

> If I edited it, it could mean that the answer provided becomes odd / irrelevant. On the other hand, I might get some more precise answers

and this is something that you **should not do**. However, you also say

> There's already an answer there that tells me I'm wrong, trying to explain the "~"-symbol which I didn't actually ask about (since I know it).

So the answer is already odd/irrelevant, since it addresses something you didn't ask about. The fact that you are getting answers tangentially related to your question shows that your question is completely clear, and **should be improved**.

Comment: You're right, so my question is basically: "How can I make my question clear without making the answer irrellevant?". Maybe I should just edit the question to ask something that he answers and then ask another question?

Comment: You should *never* edit and answer to ask something. If you have a question about an ansewr, post it as a comment on the answer.

Comment: And if the answer is already irrelevant before the edit, you shouldn't be concerned about whether it will be relevant after the edit.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong articulation, I meant edit the _question_, not the answer. And to your second comment: But the answer has upvotes, so I think it'll be cruel to make the answer more irrelevant, since some people apparently think it is relevant.

Comment: Hm. I guess it really depends how you would edit/change your question. Reading the question and answer, it seems the answer is in fact relevant (although it differs from the answer linked in the first comment on your question). In this case I'd say you should ask a new question, but be careful to tailor it specifically to what you are asking.

Comment: I think that's easier said than done. I've spent my entire time on SO trying to learn how to tailor my questions to be specific, yet include enough context, and I personally think I still suck pretty badly. I think I'm primarily concerned about this question because I'm afraid of losing so much rep that I lose the basic privileges (I have low rep in the first place). I think I'll just leave the question be for now.